# Downgrading to ios 4.1 from ios 5 without shsh?

Tags: ios

I am looking for a way to downgrade to ios4 without having SHSH.

I found some tutorial one of this a youtube video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdMHvRsplnw

That say it's possibile to downgrade to ios 4.1. Has anyone tested?

I just can stay with ios5, everything has become too slow (especially the standard Music Library of my ipod touch)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. Without SHSH blobs it is not possible. And devices running the A5 (iPad 2 and iPhone 4S) it is not possible even with the blobs.

Comment: I did it with my ipod touch 3.. i installed ios 4.3... dunno how is it possibile

Comment: @yes123 The iPod Touch 3G doesn't have an A5. It uses a variant of the 3GS's ARM7 processor. Even the iPod Touch 4G didn't carry the A5 (making use of the A4). However, my answer is an oversimplification. Technically, it has to do with the bootrom, not the chipset. Any device capable of being "owned" by the limerain exploit can be manipulated to a far greater extent than those that are not susceptible (like the 4S and the iPad 2/3).

Comment: I have downgraded to ios 4.3 because ios 5 on my ipod touch 3 was compeltly slow. What's the idea behind apple decision to don't permit downgrade? They slow down older devices with new iOS and they doen't permit downgrade. This sux

Comment: @yes123 They want everyone using the same version and also the newest one. For technical support, it makes their lives a lot easier. It also ensures a heightened user experience as the latest versions crush bugs and generally introduce new features. Apple is quite committed to user satisfaction and they do always keep a mindful eye on performance vs. new features. Downgrading is possible for the first couple of days (without SHSH blobs or any hacks), but only available till they close their signing window. After that, well, see above.

Comment: the problem is that they voluntary kills performance with new iOS on older devices. On my iPod touch 3g ios 5 is just awfully slow. And my ipod can perfectly run Infinity Blade 2 just to say.